# How could the result of Arc::clone have a 'static lifetime?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, closures, lifetime, borrow-checker

Let's begin with a canonical example of `Arc`

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let msg = Arc::new(Mutex::new(String::new()));
    let mut handles = Vec::new();
    for _ in 1..10 {
        let local_msg = Arc::clone(&msg);
        handles.push(thread::spawn(move || {
            let mut locked = local_msg.lock().unwrap();
            locked.push_str("hello, world\n");
        }));
    }

    for handle in handles {
        handle.join().unwrap();
    }

    println!("{}", msg.lock().unwrap());
}
```

This compiles and runs as expected. Then I realized maybe the `Mutex` doesn't have to live on the heap and started wondering if I can get rid of `Arc` and just use a shared reference to a `Mutex` allocated on the stack. Here is my attempt

```
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let msg = Mutex::new(String::new());
    let mut handles = Vec::new();
    for _ in 1..10 {
        let local_msg = &msg;
        handles.push(thread::spawn(move || {
            let mut locked = local_msg.lock().unwrap();
            locked.push_str("hello, world\n");
        }));
    }

    for handle in handles {
        handle.join().unwrap();
    }

    println!("{}", msg.lock().unwrap());
}
```

This one doesn't compile, though

```
error[E0597]: `msg` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:8:25
   |
8  |           let local_msg = &msg;
   |                           ^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
9  |           handles.push(thread::spawn(move || {
   |  ______________________-
10 | |             let mut locked = local_msg.lock().unwrap();
11 | |             locked.push_str("hello, world\n");
12 | |         }));
   | |__________- argument requires that `msg` is borrowed for `'static`
...
20 |   }
   |   - `msg` dropped here while still borrowed

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0597`.
error: could not compile `hello`

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

The compiler complains that `local_msg` doesn't have a `'static` lifetime. Well, it doesn't, so the error makes sense. However, this implies the variable `let local_msg = Arc::clone(&msg);` in the first snippet has `'static` lifetime, otherwise I should get a similar error.

Questions:

- How could `Arc::clone(&msg)` get a `'static` lifetime? The value it points to isn't known at compile-time, and could die before the whole program exits.
- As a bonus, what about other heap-backed smart pointers like `Box` and `Rc`? Do they all have a `'static` lifetime because the borrow checker ensures that as long as these pointers are visible, then the addresses they point to are always valid?

Comment: "The value it points to isn't known at compile-time, and could die before the whole program exits" - but it won't die before the Arc itself dies, and that's what is important.

Comment: `T: 'static` doesn't mean that `T` lives until the end of the program, but that its owner can hold on to it as long as they like. For that to be possible, `T` must contain owned data like `String` and *if* it contains references, then they have to have `'static` lifetime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing the compiler is looking for is a lifetime *bound.* A lifetime bound of `'a` doesn't mean “this type is a reference with lifetime `'a`”, but rather “all of the references this type contains have lifetimes of *at least* `'a`”.

(When a lifetime bound is written explicitly, it looks like `where T: 'a`.)

Thus, any type which *does not contain* any references (or rather, has no lifetime parameters) automatically satisfies the `'static` lifetime bound. If `T: 'static`, then `Arc<T>: 'static` (and the same for `Box` and `Rc`).

> How could `Arc::clone(&msg)` get a 'static lifetime? The value it points to isn't known at compile-time, and could die before the whole program exits.

It does not point to the value *using a reference*, so it's fine. The type of your value is `Arc<Mutex<String>>`; there are no lifetime parameters here because there are no references. If it were, hypothetically, `Arc<'a, Mutex<String>>` (a lifetime parameter which `Arc` doesn't actually have), then that type would not satisfy the bound.

The job of `Arc` (or `Rc` or `Box`) is to *own* the value it points to. Ownership is not a reference and thus not subject to lifetimes.

However, if you had the type `Arc<Mutex<&'a str>>` then that would not satisfy the bound, because it *contains a reference* which is not `'static`.